# JavaScript function not respoding at first click

Tags: javascript, onclick, avatar

I have this on HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/changeImage.js"></script>
  <img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="./images/avatars/1.png"/>
```

This is the function

```
var cc=0;

function changeImage(){
  if(cc==-1){
      cc=0;
      document.getElementById('myimage').src="./images/avatars/1.png";
      } else if (cc==0){
      cc=1;
      document.getElementById('myimage').src="./images/avatars/2.png";
      } else if (cc==1){
      cc=2;
      document.getElementById('myimage').src="./images/avatars/3.png";
      } else if (cc==2){
      cc=0;
      document.getElementById('myimage').src="./images/avatars/4.png";
      } 
    }
```

I must click 2 times to change the image. I tried some tricks but nothing.

Comment: *"i tried some tricks but nothing....."* Such as? What you should try is using the debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on the `if(cc==-1)` line, and do the click, and then walk through the code with the debugger.

Comment: Tricks? It's a one-liner using `%`... try to avoid the tricks.

Comment: I have try this code in my local system. It working fine with clicking of single click.

Comment: i have 2 more <scripts>blalba</scripts> without them on page this change avatar works great :|:| ... edit: i change the orther of <scripts> in head and now everything works good from the first click... lol :|:|......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i must click 2 times to change the image ...

At a guess, I'd say that `cc` starts out being `-1`, and so you follow this branch through your code:

```
cc=0;
document.getElementById('myimage').src="./images/avatars/1.png";
```

Since that's setting the same path that's already on the image, nothing changes. But then `cc` is `0`, so the second click follows the next branch.

---

BTW, this is what `switch` statements are for:

```
function changeImage() {
    switch (cc) {
        case -1:
            document.getElementById('myimage').src = "./images/avatars/1.png";
            break;
        case 0:
            document.getElementById('myimage').src = "./images/avatars/2.png";
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById('myimage').src = "./images/avatars/3.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById('myimage').src = "./images/avatars/4.png";
            break;
    }
    cc = cc == 2 ? 0 : cc + 1;
}
```

Or a map:

```
var imageMap = {
    -1: "./images/avatars/1.png",
    0:  "./images/avatars/2.png",
    1:  "./images/avatars/3.png",
    2:  "./images/avatars/4.png"
};
function changeImage() {

    document.getElementById('myimage').src = imageMap[cc];
    cc = cc == 2 ? 0 : cc + 1;
}
```

In both of the above, I've replicated the logic of your `if/else` series, but note that the logic of your `if/else` series never lets you get back to `1.png`.

Also note that I'm assuming the real image paths are more complex, because otherwise you'd just want to key off the fact that you have `1.png`, `2.png`, etc.

Comment: only th first time i start from 0 after this i start every time from -1